# Use both Windows Authentication and Login forms in Same Identity as a service(IDaaS)

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

I have two applications (WPF and Angular with asp.net Web API 4.8 ) , I want a SSO (single sign on) authentication for both by automatically federated with on-premises active directory AD and Login Forms for added users by Admin in each application

1. if the user exist in the AD then will be Authenticated , else show a login Form to check if its in DB
2. if the user logged-in from each application don't have to login again in the second application (apply SSO)

Any Ideas in which Identity should I apply that fit this requirement ?

I found Identity Server 3 but its not recommended to use as its no more under support or development , and Identity Server 4 works with asp.net core and I use Asp.net web API 4.8 ,
Can I Apply that with Asp.net Identity ?